# How to exclude certain variables from recipe?

Tags: r, r-caret, r-recipes

When using the `step_regex` function to build a recipe for a model, it creates additional columns for certain patterns in the original column. Is there way to exclude the original column from the recipe once I'm done with it?

For example in the example below, the product contains both original `description` column and two newly created by `step_regex`. I want a solution that's integrated with the `recipe` object, so that I can use it directly in the `caret::train`.

```
library(recipe)
data(covers)

rec <- recipe(~ description, covers) %>%
  step_regex(description, pattern = "(rock|stony)", result = "rocks") %>%
  step_regex(description, pattern = "ratake families")

rec2 <- prep(rec, training = covers)

with_dummies <- bake(rec2, newdata = covers)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found the solution. I think I can change the role for the columns I don't want to be used as predictors.

`rec <- rec %>% add_role(description, new_role = "dont_use")`

Answer (score 1):

With the update to [recipes >=0.20](https://recipes.tidymodels.org/news/index.html#recipes-020), bake() will now error if new_data doesn’t contain all the required columns. The recommended solution is to use [update_role_requirements()](https://recipes.tidymodels.org/reference/update_role_requirements.html).

```
rec <- rec %>% update_role_requirements(role = "dont_use", bake = FALSE)
```